# How to build a TypeScript class constructor with object defining class fields?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript it's possible to create a class with a constructor that takes parameter with access modifiers and it automatically convert those parameters in class fields.

```
class Item {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public updatedAt: number,
    public createdAt: number,
  ) {}
}

const item = new Item(1, 1, 1);
item.id // 1
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to pass all those parameters in an object instead

```
class Item {
  constructor({
    public id: number,
    public updatedAt: number,
    public createdAt: number,
  }) {}
}

const item = new Item({ id: 1, updatedAt: 1, createdAt: 1 });
item.id // 1
```

Is this possible? Ever gonna be possible?

Are there workarounds to do something similar?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The simplest way would be to declare the fields in the class and use a mapped type as a parameter, then use `Object.assign` to assign the fields to `this`. We have several options for which mapped type to use:

**`Partial<T>`**

Type will contain all members (fields and methods) of the class but all of them are optional. The disadvantage here is we can't make some of the fields required, and the caller can potentially override a method

```
class Item {

    public id: number;
    public updatedAt: number;
    public createdAt: number;
    constructor(data: Partial<Item>) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
    method() {}
}

//Works 
const item = new Item({ id: 1, updatedAt: 1, createdAt: 1 });
//This also works unfortunately 
const item2 = new Item({ id: 1, method() { console.log('overriden from param !')} });
```

**`Pick<T, K>`**

This mapped type allows us to pick some properties from `T` by specifying a union of several string literal types that are keys of `T`. The advantages are that `Pick` will inherit whether the field is required or not from the original declaration in the class (so some fields can be required and other optional) and since we specify which members we pick, we can omit methods. The disadvantage is that we have to write property names twice (once in the class and once in the Pick):

```
class Item {
    public id: number;
    public updatedAt?: number;
    public createdAt?: number;
    constructor(data: Pick<Item, "id" | "updatedAt" | "createdAt">) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
    method() {}
}
const item = new Item({ id: 1  }); //id is required others fields are not
const item2 = new Item({ id: 1, method() {}  }); // error method is not allowed
```

**Custom Mapped Type That Removes Methods**

The third option would be create a type similar to `Pick` that includes all class fields but not the methods automatically. We can do this in Typescript 2.8 using conditional types (unrelease at the time of writing, but should be release in March 2018, you can get it right now via `npm install -g typescript@next`). This has the advantages of `Pick` without the need to specify filed names again:

```
type NonMethodKeys<T> = {[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Function ? never : P }[keyof T];  
type RemoveMethods<T> = Pick<T, NonMethodKeys<T>>; 

class Item {
    public id!: number;
    public updatedAt?: number;
    public createdAt?: number;
    constructor(data: RemoveMethods<Item>) { // No need to specify field names again
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
    method() {}
}

const item = new Item({ id: 1  });  //id is required others fields are not
const item2 = new Item({ id: 1, method() {}  }); // error method is not allowed
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: What if the initializer is in a parent class and you want the constructor class of the child to take only the child's class properties and not the parent's also?

Comment: "we can't make some of the fields required". We can, using a custom utility type. `type SomeRequired<T, K extends keyof T> = Omit<T, K> & Partial<T>`

Comment: TS will probably hate on you for using Object.assign like that.

Property 'x' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)

Comment: @backdesk True. The compiler will not know about the assignment of the fields. You can add a `!` to the fields to silence it.

Comment: Indeed you can @TitianCernicova-Dragomir. It's a shame though because I like that pattern. Just more time spent fighting TypeScript dogma.

Comment: @backdesk Open a GH ticket. The pattern is simple enough to recognize, the compiler could recognize the assignment.  You might also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53128744/typescript-automatically-get-interface-properties-in-a-class

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir May I ask you why I need to add `& { [x: string]: never }` part to build `NonMethodKeys`?

Comment: @ChangdaePark this is a really old answer, might have been required back then to index with `keyof T`. I removed it since it no longer appears to be needed. Thanks for bringing it to my attention

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve similar behavior by creating an interface:

```
interface IProps {
  id: number;
  updatedAt: number;
  createdAt: number;
}

class Item {
  constructor(public props: IProps) {}
}

const item = new Item({ id: 1, updatedAt: 1, createdAt: 1 });
console.log(item.props.id);
```

Comment: But now id is in a props object, but the op wanted id to become a property of Item

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Titian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49062616/1099227), if you don't want to copy paste the `RemoveMethods` type, then you can achieve this with `type-fest`'s [`ConditionalExcept`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/conditional-except.d.ts):

```js
import { ConditionalExcept } from 'type-fest';

class Item {
  required_property!: int;
  optional_property?: string;

  constructor(object: ConditionalExcept<Item, Function>) {
    Object.assign(this, object);
  }
  method() {}
}
```