# Instantiate javascript class with object in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm not sure if I can't find an answer to this because it is not possible, but I find myself wanting to instantiate a class with an object like so:

```
class Foo {    
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public bar: string,
    public y: number,
    public z: string
  ) {}    
}

let x = new Foo({bar: 'testing', z: 'test'})
```

Instead, this will attempt to set `id` equal to `{bar: 'testing', z: 'test'}` which is not what I want.  I'd like it to create an instance of `Foo` with `Foo.bar = 'testing'` and `Foo.z = 'test'`.

Is the only way to define the object like `new Foo(null, 'testing', null, 'test')`?

Comment: This looks like a candidate for ["object destructuring"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Comment: Also look at this question for a more TS oriented solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061774/how-to-build-a-typescript-class-constructor-with-object-defining-class-fields/49062616#49062616