# Dynamic interface definition

Tags: typescript

I have abstract base class for a bunch of "schema definition" classes:

> `xyz` extends `BaseSchema`

What I want to ensure is that the parent schema classes are exporting meaningful constraints/interfaces for the schema's properties (and eventually for it's relationships). So right now the base class is defined as:

```
export abstract class BaseSchema {
  /** The primary-key for the record */
  @property public id?: string;
  /** The last time that a given model was updated */
  @property public lastUpdated?: datetime;
  /** The datetime at which this record was first created */
  @property public createdAt?: datetime;
  /** Metadata properties of the given schema */
  public META?: Partial<ISchemaOptions>;

  public toString() {
    const obj: IDictionary = {};
    this.META.properties.map(p => {
      obj[p.property] = (this as any)[p.property];
    });
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
  }

  public toJSON() {
    return this.toString();
  }
}
```

The an example parent class might look like so:

```
export class Person extends BaseSchema {
  // prettier-ignore
  @property @length(20) public name: string;
  @property public age?: number;
  @property public gender?: "male" | "female" | "other";
  // prettier-ignore
  @property @pushKey public tags?: IDictionary<string>;

  // prettier-ignore
  @ownedBy(Person) @inverse("children") public motherId?: fk;
  // prettier-ignore
  @ownedBy(Person) @inverse("children") public fatherId?: fk;
  @hasMany(Person) public children?: fk[];

  @ownedBy(Company) public employerId?: fk;
}
```

Now you'll notice that I am using Typescript's support for **decorators** and in this case the main thing to understand about the decorator code is that the `@property` decorator is used to explicitly state a property on the schema. This stamps meta information about the properties of the schema into a dictionary object on the schema class's `META.proproperties`. You'll see this is used later on in the `toString()` method. If you feel the actual decorator code is important to understand you can find it [HERE](https://github.com/forest-fire/firemodel/tree/master/src/decorators).

What I *want* to be able to do is expose an interface definition that constrains the type to the properties and types of those properties defined in the schema. Something like the following:

```
 function foobar(person PersonProperties) { ... }
```

so that the property "person" would be constrained by the properties that are required and that the *intellisense* in the editor would offer both required (aka, "name") and unrequired properties (aka, "age", "createdAt", etc.) defined as properties.

Eventually I'd like to export a type that does the same thing for relationships but I'd be happy to just get the schema's properties for now.

Answer (score 2):

In typescript 2.8 you can use [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) and [mapped types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12114) to create a type that contains only the fields of the class not the methods, and preserves the required/optional attribute of the field:

```
type NonMethodKeys<T> = {[P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Function ? never : P }[keyof T];  
type RemoveMethods<T> = Pick<T, NonMethodKeys<T>>; 

class Person {
  public name: string;
  public age?: number;
  public gender?: "male" | "female" | "other";
  toJson(): string { return ''}
}

let ok: RemoveMethods<Person> = {
  name : 'Snow',
  gender: 'male'
};

// Error no name
let nokNoName: RemoveMethods<Person> = {
};

let nok: RemoveMethods<Person> = {
  name : 'Snow',
  gender: 'male',
  toJson(): string { return ''}  // error unknown property
};
```

If you are using Typescript 2.7 or lower, there are no conditional types, and you can only use mapped type such as `Pick` or `Partial`. For a discussion as to their relative advantages you can see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061774/how-to-build-a-typescript-class-constructor-with-object-defining-class-fields/49062616#49062616)

Unfortunately there is no way to use decorators to discern what fields make it into the interface, we can only use the type of the field. You might consider a design where you class only has fields that are also properties, or where such fields are held in a special class that contains only properties.

There is always the option of defining an extra interface with just the properties explicitly but this will add extra maintenance hassle.

Comment: Yes I am trying to avoid the explicit interfaces as that seems redundant. I can, however, enforce 2.8+ so at least the conditional types are an option. I'm "pre-caffeinated" so let me digest this over caffeine intake. Either way, thanks for your expert insight.

Comment: I have upgraded to TS `2.8.3` but I am getting the following error from your type definition for `NonMethodKeys`: https://www.screencast.com/t/x9okhgOaxO . Not sure what I'm running into.

Comment: I can turn off the warning with `tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression` but hate turning off things I'm not understanding.

Comment: @ken not sure why you get that error, is tslint also up to date ? maybe it does not understand the new conditional type syntax

Comment: @ken I know you are trying to avoid defining an extra interface, I am trying an out of the box approach but to get something  like what you want, but I'm not sure it's actually usable... more for academic purposes, I will let you know if I mange to get something fully featured.

Comment: @ken How set are you on using decorators ? If what you want can be more easily achieved with a different approach, would you be interested in it ?

Comment: I would ideally like to stick with the decorators approach but not 100% sold on it. What am I giving up by choosing that style?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168154/discussion-between-titian-cernicova-dragomir-and-ken).