# Map `ConstructorParameters<T>` tuple to object type

Tags: typescript

I wonder if there is any way of mapping `ConstructorParameters<T>` to an object where each key is the parameter name and the key is the type of the parameter.

What I mean is, given:

```js
class User {
  public id: number;

  constructor(
      public readonly name: string,
      public readonly surname: string,
  ) {}

  get fullname(): string { ... }
  public isAdmin(): boolean { ... }
}
```

With `ConstructorParameters<typeof User>` I get the type `[name: string, surname: string]`. Maybe this can be mapped to the following type `{ name: string, surname: string }`? **Note** that the type should omit: `id`, `fullname` & `isAdmin` as they are not present on the constructor.

I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/49062616 which is a really cool solution but it breaks with getters and public properties that are not present in the constructor.

Comment: Why not `type UserMapped = { [P in keyof User]: User[P]; }` ?

Comment: That returns everything public, including the methods, the getters and other public properties not defined in the constructor. In this case I only want to map the constructor parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. The "name" of the parameters of a function don't actually have any meaning outside the context of the function. For example, you can do this:

```
type FuncType = (foo: string) => void;

const MyFunc: FuncType = (bar) => {
  return bar;
}
```

The "name" of `foo` and `bar` don't match at all, but the *order* and *type* do, which is all that really matters. Probably similar to how you can destructure an array and give the items arbitrary names; the items in an array don't *have* names to begin with:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3];
const [one, two, three] = array;
```

About the closest you could probably get is to get the order and types of your constructor as an object, but I'm not sure how that would be useful:

```
type ConstructorParametersIndices<T extends new (...args: any) => any> =
  T extends new (...args: infer P) => any ? {[K in keyof P]: K} : never;

type A = ConstructorParameters<typeof User>;
// [name: string, surname: string]

type B = ConstructorParametersIndices<typeof User>;
// [name: "0", surname: "1"]

type C = {[P in B[number] as P]: A[P]};
/*  {
 *    0: string;
 *    1: string;
/*  }
```

Comment: I see, as you mention, I have the impression that what I'm asking is not possible. Although, it's weird as from the VS Code hint looks like TS has knowledge of parameter name, that's why I though that maybe there was a way. When it's user defined tuple it's just the array of types…

Comment: @doup yeah it feels as if there should be some way to access the parameter "name" but I could not find one, it seems it's only there se some kind of hinting.