# Looking for a way to lower public class property type redundancy

Tags: typescript, class

Typically when you have a class with many parameters, you pass in an object. It's relatively easy then to have a class that passes around it's single parameter within the class nested, something like this:

```
interface CalendarOptions {
  calendarDate?: Date | string,
  todaysDate?: Date | string,
  weeklyAvailability?: {[key: string]: string[]},
  startOfWeek?: number,
  weekdayNames?: string[],
  todayAvailable?: boolean,
  showMonths?: number,
  disablePrevMonths?: boolean,
  events?: {start: Date, end: Date}[],
}

const defaultCalendarOptions: CalendarOptions = {
  calendarDate: new Date(),
  todaysDate: new Date(),
  weeklyAvailability: {},
  startOfWeek: 0,
  weekdayNames: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
  todayAvailable: false,
  showMonths: 2,
  disablePrevMonths: false,
  events: []
}

class Calendar  {
  // this doesn't really make it easy to specify some options as partial and othes not
  options: Required<CalendarOptions>
  constructor (options: CalendarOptions = defaultCalendarOptions) {
    // still have to do this to make sure all options defaulted even when a partial is passed in
    this.options = {...defaultCalendarOptions, ...options}
  }

  get example () {
    // use properties this.options.startOfWeek
  }
}
```

However if you want to use the properties passed into the class in the instance you have to call the nested options param:

```
const x = new Calendar({ startOfWeek: 2 })
x.options.startOfWeek
```

While this is the easiest way of doing it I'm unable to access the options at the "top level" of the class.

Another approach would be to detructure all of the options like this defining default values through the destructuring

```
class Calendar  {
  // you have to repeat the types at the top level
  calendarDate: NonNullable<CalendarOptions['calendarDate']>
  todaysDate: NonNullable<CalendarOptions['todaysDate']>
  weeklyAvailability: NonNullable<CalendarOptions['WeeklyAvailability']>
  startOfWeek: NonNullable<CalendarOptions['startOfWeek']>
  weekdayNames: NonNullable<CalendarOptions['weekdayNames']>
  todayAvailable: NonNullable<CalendarOptions['todayAvailable']>
  showMonths: NonNullable<CalendarOptions['showMonths']>
  disablePrevMonths: NonNullable<CalendarOptions['disablePrevMonths']>
  events: NonNullable<CalendarOptions['events']>
  constructor (
    options: CalendarOptions = {}
  ) {
    const {
      calendarDate = new Date(),
      todaysDate = new Date(),
      weeklyAvailability = {},
      startOfWeek = 0,
      weekdayNames = ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
      todayAvailable = false,
      showMonths = 2,
      disablePrevMonths = false,
      events = []
    } = options
    this.calendarDate = calendarDate
    this.todaysDate = todaysDate
    this.weeklyAvailability = weeklyAvailability
    this.startOfWeek = startOfWeek
    this.weekdayNames = weekdayNames
    this.todayAvailable = todayAvailable
    this.showMonths = showMonths
    this.disablePrevMonths = disablePrevMonths
    this.events = events
  }
}
```

A third approach is to define actual class parameters and have a function that allows for the object:

```
class Calendar {

  constructor (
    /** the current calendar month show */
    public calendarDate: Date | string = new Date(),
    /** todays date independent of the calendar show */
    public todaysDate: Date | string = new Date(),
    /** days and times durring the week you are available */
    public weeklyAvailability: {[key: string]: string[]} = {},
    /** changes the start day of the week defaults to sunday  */
    public startOfWeek: number = 0,
    /** changes the prefix used for the days of the week (eg. Su, Mo, Tu) */
    public weekdayNames: string[] = ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
    /** should today be available on your calendar */
    public todayAvailable: boolean = false,
    /** how many months in the future do you want to provide defaults to 2 */
    public showMonths: number = 2,
    /** should you be able to access prior months to current calendarDate */
    public disablePrevMonths: boolean = false,
    /** events you currently have on your calendar or times you don't want people to book */
    public events: {start: Date, end: Date}[] = []
  ) {}
 
  static fromInput ({
    calendarDate,
    todaysDate,
    weeklyAvailability,
    startOfWeek,
    weekdayNames,
    todayAvailable,
    showMonths,
    disablePrevMonths,
    events,
  }: {
    calendarDate?: Calendar['calendarDate'],
    todaysDate?: Calendar['todaysDate'],
    weeklyAvailability?: Calendar['weeklyAvailability'],
    startOfWeek?: Calendar['startOfWeek'],
    weekdayNames?: Calendar['weekdayNames'],
    todayAvailable?: Calendar['todayAvailable'],
    showMonths?: Calendar['showMonths'],
    disablePrevMonths?: Calendar['disablePrevMonths'],
    events?: Calendar['events'],
  }): Calendar {
    return new Calendar(
      calendarDate,
      todaysDate,
      weeklyAvailability,
      startOfWeek,
      weekdayNames,
      todayAvailable,
      showMonths,
      disablePrevMonths,
      events,
    )
  }
}
```

With this option you have to keep in mind the **order** of the arguments passed into the class.

All of these options have a ton of duplication, duplicating variable names and types, and I'm looking for a simpler, better, less code, solution that would allow me to have an object of options passed into a class and have the properties set at the root level. Keeping in mind that the single-parameter object may have optional values that the class may have default values for, so the "internal" type of the options should be different than the "external" type that may be  or have optional values.

Comment: More or less a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69291358/2887218) which would suggest a solution like [this one](https://tsplay.dev/weQAEw) except for the part where you say "this doesn't really make it easy to specify some options as partial and others not", but if that's important you should make your example code show the need for it.  Am I missing something?  (Pls mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Comment: Found similar post here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49061774/how-to-build-a-typescript-class-constructor-with-object-defining-class-fields

Comment: So, do those questions cover this one or is there something missing?  We should either close this as a duplicate or you should [edit] to highlight anything that makes the other ones inappropriate.